# PHP Google Api Code Exchange Results In "invalid_grant"

Tags: youtube-api, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-client

I realize there's about 20 of these posts, but I've looked through all of them and no answer has helped thus far (although has helped me rule things out).

I'm writing a bunch of Youtube related api functions in PHP, and I have no issues grabbing data once I have an access code (and also no issues refreshing an access code), but when I try to exchange the authorization code for an access token, I receive the "invalid_grant" response.

I also need offline access because I plan to make api calls without the user interacting, and pre-authorizing the accounts is not an option.

#### Notes:

- I've de-authorized every test with the OAuth playground
- I've set "**ntpdate **" on my unix system to google
- refreshing tokens works
- if I remove **urlencode** from the code and request uri string I receive an "**invalid request**" error. The funny thing is it doesn't require it on the refresh token function.

### Code

access.php

```
$ytclient = new ytClient;

if(isset($_GET['code'])){
  $ytclient->auth_code = $_GET['code'];
  $ytclient->exchangeToken();
}else{
  $ytclient->authorize();
}
```

ytClient

```
function authorize(){
  include('config.php');
  echo "<script>window.location = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=".urlencode( $config->domain.'/lib/access.php')."&response_type=code&client_id=**************&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyt-analytics-monetary.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyt-analytics.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutubepartner&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline'</script>";
}
function exchangeToken(){
  $postArr["client_id"] = ($config->ytclientid);
  $postArr["client_secret"] = ($config->ytclientsecret);
  $postArr["code"] = urlencode($this->auth_code);
  $postArr["request_uri"] = urlencode($config->domain."/lib/access.php");
  $postArr["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";
  $accessObj = $this->get_yt_json("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", $postArr, 1);
}

function get_yt_json($url, $postArr, $mode){
  if($mode == 1){
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArr);
  }elseif($mode == 2){
    $url .= "?".http_build_query($postArr);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
  }
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $rawJson = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  echo $rawJson;
  /*
  $obj = json_decode($rawJson);

  return ($obj);
  */
}
```

response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
Pragma: no-cache 
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT 
Date: Sat, 21 Sep 2013 18:58:31 GMT 
Content-Type: application/json 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block 
Server: GSE 
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 

{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }
```

Comment: Can you paste the actual requests and responses off the wire

Answer (score 1):

Never found a solution, but fixed it by using the highly undocumented google php api => https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

Quick and easy solution -- and magic as far as I know... Here's the code to authenticate someone with a lifetime token using the api, might help someone:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner');

/* Auth the client and get Token Object */
$auth = $client->authenticate();
$token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
```

Comment: Actually those are highly documented. They can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php). You can find them for other services too [here](https://developers.google.com)